# How can I create a drop down list for file path with wxpython?

Tags: wxpython

I'm trying to develop a drop-down list for the file path. The user can use the drop-down list to show where a file is located. I don't really know how to link the drop-down list to the directories. I would really appreciate it if someone can help me with this.

Comment: As it currently stands, your question is a bit vague. Could you flesh out what you envision `the file path` to be and its context. Perhaps add the code that you have already written.

Comment: What am envision is a Combobox that links to the directory and the user can choose a particular file from it. I don't know if I'm making any sense here.

Comment: See my answer to this question, somehow they feel related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57256881/how-to-set-the-directory-path-in-wxpython/57258169?noredirect=1#comment101076744_57258169

Comment: Perhaps the FileBrowseButtonWithHistory (https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.lib.filebrowsebutton.html) is what you are looking for.