# how to set the directory path in wxpython

Tags: wxpython

I would like to set the path of the directory and it searches for that particular path and lists all the files in it.

For Examples, I need to set path of the directory A = C:\Users\Downloads, B = C:\Users\Documents, C = C:\Users\Desktop in the code. And when A is selected it needs to load the above specified directory and list all the files in listbox.

1. How to set the directory for each elements(A,B,C..) ----> I tried using **wx.DirDialog** but it always loads the last selected or default directory.
2. When any element is selected it should load the specified  directory in the code and lists the files.

Comment: wx.DirDialog will work for you - look at the `defaultPath` param.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple starting point.
It uses `wx.FileDialog` as you wish to list files not directories (wx.DirDialog).
Select a directory from a `wx.Choice` which activates the dialog, to list the files within that directory.
Currently the program only prints a list of selected files, I leave the loading of a listbox to you.

```
import wx

class choose(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Dialog")
        mychoice = ['Select a directory','/home/rolf', '/home/public','/home/public/Documents']
        panel = wx.Panel(self,-1)
        select_dir = wx.Choice(panel,-1, choices=mychoice, pos=(20,20))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHOICE, self.OnSelect)
        self.dir = mychoice[0]
        select_dir.SetSelection(0)
        self.Show()

    def OnSelect(self, event):
        if event.GetSelection() == 0:
            return
        self.dir = event.GetString()
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(None, message="Choose a file/files", defaultDir = self.dir, style=wx.FD_MULTIPLE)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            print('Selected files are: ', dlg.GetPaths())
        dlg.Destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_app = wx.App()
    choose(None)
    my_app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggesting wx.FileDialog and it works. Now I would like to change a question little bit, here is there is no need to choose a file or directory by the user. For example, when the user gives the input 'some name', it should know which directory to be loaded to search. So may be like a table format, if this is the input [A = C:\Users\Downloads, B = C:\Users\Documents, C = C:\Users\Desktop] should be written in the code.

Comment: I don't understand what it is that you are suggesting, that is materially different to the answer provided.

Comment: sorry if its not clear. Instead the selection done by user , i would like to have a background search and listing the files. The input by the user  should only be the keyword and  I would like to set the path for each keyword(A,B,C,...) and when that keyword is selected in the dropdown , it should know which directory to search and list the files present in it. For example, Keywords A should navigate some directory, B should navigate other directory. which directory should the keyword navigate can be defined inside the code. dropdown and listbox works but how to set relative path for keywords.

Comment: All I get is the vague feeling that you are trying to reinvent a wheel. Can I suggest that you edit your answer and add a `worked example` of what it is that you are trying to achieve, without using keyword A, directory B.